# Change Media MetaData in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change a media item's metadata value (for this example, the 'caption' value). This can be done manually via the Media page, but I need to do it via a function.

I am using this code, which is able to read the metadata, but cannot change/write a new value to the 'caption' field.

Several 'print_r' so that you can see the values before and after

```
function ml_change_media_data() {
    // assumes that the 'caption' for the picture contains text (via media edit screen)
    // set up the test media ID number and other items
    global $post;
    $post_id = 620; // hardcoded for now; change for your testing
    $caption_new = "this is new caption";

    // read the current media meta data
        $data = wp_get_attachment_metadata($post_id, $unfiltered);
// this shows that the existing 'caption' is an empty array element
echo "data before change <pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre><hr>";

    // this function gets the actual caption element (matches what we see in edit screen)
    $pix_meta = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $post_id);
    // shows the real caption value
echo "pix_meta via prepare function <pre>";print_r($pix_meta);echo "</pre><hr>";

    // change the caption element  to the $caption_new value
    $pix_meta[caption] = $caption_new;
echo "pix_meta after changing caption element <pre>";print_r($pix_meta);echo "</pre><hr>";

    // write the media meta data
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $pix_meta );   

    // read the metadata again
    $pix_meta_now = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js( $post_id);

    // this next should show the new caption value, but the caption has NOT changed 
echo "pix_meta_now after change - did it change ? <pre>";print_r($pix_meta_now);echo "</pre><hr>";
    die();
    return;
}
```

Looking at the media item in the Media page, the caption has not changed.

Note that the 'wp_get_attachment_metadata' function returns an array that includes a 'caption' element, but that element is blank; which doesn't match the caption shown on the Media screen.

Here is what 'wp_get_attachment_metadata' returns from a media item that shows caption text in the Media screen.

```
 [image_meta] => Array
        (
            [aperture] => 0
            [credit] => 
            [camera] => 
            [caption] => 
            [created_timestamp] => 0
            [copyright] => 
            [focal_length] => 0
            [iso] => 0
            [shutter_speed] => 0
            [title] => 
            [orientation] => 0
        [keywords] => Array
                (
                )
        )
```

So I use the 'wp_prepare_attachment_for_js' function to return the actual 'caption' value:

```
 [caption] => the current caption
```

So my problem is how to **write** to the 'caption' element of the media item?

Thanks...Rick...